# Date of videos seen differently by Picasa and by the filesystem

Tags: macos, video, picasa

I have several photos and videos in a particular picasa folder, which I've sorted by date. But I've noticed that some of the videos are appearing out of order. Upon closer inspection, I see the date used (and shown) by picasa doesn't match the file date for that video...

**Example**

Listing the files on a terminal window shows these dates:

```
$  ls -laT  *.MOV
-rwxrwxrwx  1 fcorreia  staff  39118974 Apr 17 11:18:42 2012 MVI_7707.MOV
-rwxrwxrwx  1 fcorreia  staff   1532198 Apr 17 11:22:40 2012 MVI_7708.MOV
```

But on picasa, these two videos appear respectively with the dates `Apr 17, 2012 9:18` and `Apr 17, 2012 9:22` (I'm seeing this using the "Get Info" option available through the photos' context menu).

The dates appear to be shifted by two hours. Might this be related to timezones in some way? Where should I adjust the date or timezone to make picasa see the date I know see as the file date?

---

**Update**

@Lèse's answer pushed me in the right direction, although I still think I'm missing something...

I hadn't noticed the `Tools > Adjust date and time` option before. It's true that using it changes the date as seen by Picasa, but where this date is being saved and read from is still a mystery.

Initially, the date as shown by Picasa was different from the file's "created" and "modified" dates. This tells me that it was being read from somewhere else.

But looking at the file's info (using Finder) indicates that using the `Adjust date and time` feature also changes the "Created" date (leaving the "Modified" date intact).

Answer (score 0):

If these are the only files that have the timeshift, and your Google Apps account is set to the proper timezone, then you can just [change the time for these files](http://support.google.com/picasa/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=160761).

There are multiple reports of Picasa using the wrong time/timezone when photos/videos are uploaded from certain devices. For example, [this person has problems only with videos uploaded from his iPhone4](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/picasa/picasa-for-mac/tpK1hxVkk7M), but the iPhone itself shows the correct time for the videos. So maybe there's a bug in certain Picasa uploaders.

Comment: Thanks. The first part of your answer is *almost* satisfying :) I've updated the question with more info. The second paragraph, i think doesn't apply to my case, as I'm not using the Web Albuns, just the desktop Picasa.